# append() algorithm incorrectly appends

Tags: python, json, algorithm, list, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
sportMappings = {"sport1" : {"file" : "sport1.json", "label" : "Sport 1"},"sport2" : {"file" : "sport2.json", "label" : "Sport 2"},"sport3" : {"file" : "sport3.json", "label" : "Sport 3"}}
normalizedEntries = {"o.json" : {"spotlight" : []}}

normalizedEntries = createList(normalizedEntries, map_key, sportMappings)

def createList(normalizedEntries, key, sportMappings):
    for range in SOURCES["ranges"]: 
        data = read_files.readJSONUrl(logger, SOURCES[key] + str(range)) 
        for entry in data["entries"]: 
            normalizedEntry = normalize(entry, "type") 
            if normalizedEntry is not None: 
                #append to a catchall dict
                normalizedEntries["o.json"]["spotlight"].append(normalizedEntry) 
                if normalizedEntry["league"] in sportMappings: 
                    if sportMappings[normalizedEntry["league"]]["file"] not in normalizedEntries: 
                        normalizedEntries[sportMappings[normalizedEntry["league"]]["file"]] = {"spotlight" : []}
                    #append to the specific league to which that sport belongs...ie sport1, sport2
                    normalizedEntries[sportMappings[normalizedEntry["league"]]["file"]]["spotlight"].append(normalizedEntry) 
                else: 
                    pass

    return normalizedEntries
```

The point of which is to get a json input, iterate over each object in the json, normalize its format, then append ALL objects to o.json and then append the entry to its corresponding sport file from the sportMappings dict.

I expect that after iteration 1 normalizedEntries' contents will be :

```
--o.json
   --entryForSport2
--sport1.json
--sport2.json
   --entryForSport2
--sport3.json
```

After iteration 2 normalizedEntries' contents will be:

```
  --o.json
     --entryForSport2
     --entryForSport1
  --sport1.json
     --entryForSport1
  --sport2.json
     --entryForSport2
  --sport3.json
```

And so on.

Instead, after the function runs completely, all sub dictionaries are all the same.

```
--o.json
   --entryForSport2
   --entryForSport1
--sport1.json
   --entryForSport2
   --entryForSport1
--sport2.json
   --entryForSport2
   --entryForSport1
--sport3.json
   --entryForSport2
   --entryForSport1
```

**Question: Why are the items being appended to ALL sub dictionaries for each iteration as opposed to each item going into the catch-all o.json and then to its appropriate sport subdict?** note - "spotlight is a list, not a dict so append() should be the appropriate tool, yes?

Comment: This sounds as if you are reusing a list object somewhere, yet your code creates a *new* dictionary entry for each `file` key; are you certain the code you posted here is complete and accurate?

Comment: Crap!... the only difference is that I use a constant SPOTLIGHT = {"spotlight" : []} to initialize them rather than this {"spotlight" : []}.  I changed it in the code above to make it easier to read...  I bet that's the issue.

Comment: Oh, that is *absolutely* the issue here.

Comment: ARRRRGGGG!!!!!!!  I didn't realize that

Comment: @Brad It often happens to me that I can think of new things to try while writing a question, but it doesn't happen often that when writing the question, you inadvertently write the answer. :)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe AND don't even know you found the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a *constant* dictionary object, with a mutable list. This means you are now sharing the same dictionary object (and list object) across your structure.

The code, as posted, won't do this; replace your constant with what you posted here. :-)

If you have to use a constant (say, you need the same structure in multiple locations), use a factory function instead:

```
SPOTLIGHT = lambda: {'spotlight': []}
```

and use `SPOTLIGHT()` anywhere you need a new copy.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way you can accomplish abstracting out the literal {"spotlight" : []} from my code without encountering this error?  Can I clone it when i'm initializing these or something?

Comment: @Brad: Use a factory function to produce it. `SPOTLIGHT = lambda: {'spotlight': []}`, then use `SPOTLIGHT()` whenever you need a new copy.